# Print ascending numbers using 10 threads

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, python-multithreading

Recently I've stumbled upon an interview question designed for software engineers. The question is :

***Given 10 threads, print 1-100 in order so that thread 1 prints 1,11,21 etc (Python)***

I'm not an expert on Python by any means but I think the solution's supposed to be very simple. However I've not been able to solve this problem for 3 straight hours and it's been boggling my mind. The code that I'd come up with so far is below:

```
import threading, queue

THREADS_NUM = 10
LIMIT = 100

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    lock = threading.Lock()
    
    def __init__(self, q): 
        threading.Thread.__init__(self) 
        MyThread.lock.acquire() 
        self.id = int(self.name[7:])
        #print("My id is %d" % self.id)
        self.q = q
        MyThread.lock.release()
 
    def run(self):
        MyThread.lock.acquire()
        while True:
            try:
                #print("Right now the queue size is %d" % self.q.qsize())
                current_num = self.q.get()
                if current_num % 10 == self.id:
                    print("%s is now printing %d" % (self.id, current_num)) 
                else:
                    self.q.put(current_num)
            except queue.Empty:
                print("reached the end")
                break
            finally:
                self.q.task_done()
        MyThread.lock.release()

            

#threads = []

q = queue.Queue()
for i in range(1, LIMIT):
    q.put(i)

for i in range(1, THREADS_NUM):
    thread = MyThread(q)
    #threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

q.join()
 
#for t in threads: 
#    t.join()
```

After doing some research a bit, I saw that the easiest option would be to use synchronized **queue** and **threading** library available as default in **python3**. The question does not state what library/method I should use so I'm open to other methods.

**NOTE**

This code prints:

```
1 is now printing 1
1 is now printing 11
1 is now printing 21
1 is now printing 31
1 is now printing 41
1 is now printing 51
1 is now printing 61
1 is now printing 71
1 is now printing 81
1 is now printing 91
...hangs & never exits
```

Comment: Without giving specifics, I'd maybe look at having each thread use an `Event` https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects. Then you can chain each thread to the next thread's event, and finally, manually fire the first thread's event. Then each thread will wake up, print it's number, and then notify the next thread in the chain (via `t.event.set()`)

Comment: As for what's wrong with the above code, I haven't looked in detail. You have a single lock shared by all your threads. I think the first thread takes the lock, pulls each number from the queue, each time it finds one that ends in 1 it prints it, otherwise it puts it back in the queue. It will then keep going round and round taking numbers off the queue and putting them back forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK So I was intrigued if I could make the idea in my comment work, and it seems to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7

import threading


THREADS_NUM = 10
LIMIT = 100


class NumberPrinterThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, mod_n, initial):
        super().__init__()
        self.mod_n = mod_n
        self.n = initial
        self.e = threading.Event()
        self.next_event = None

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # Wait to be told to print
            self.e.wait()
            # Clear/reset our own event
            self.e.clear()

            print(self.n)

            # Signal the next thread to print
            self.next_event.set()

            # Exit if the next number is too big
            self.n += self.mod_n
            if self.n > LIMIT:
                return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    threads = [NumberPrinterThread(THREADS_NUM, n + 1) for n in range(THREADS_NUM)]
    for i, t in enumerate(threads):
        # Link each thread to the next
        next_thread = threads[(i + 1) % THREADS_NUM]
        t.next_event = next_thread.e

    for t in threads:
        t.start()

    # Signal the first thread
    threads[0].e.set()

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work I'm not familiar with python events so I'll look into the code and try to understand the logic. Did you take a look at my initial solution. I'd appreciate if you could tell me what went wrong in my code?